# Vue Router is not working and not displaying anything

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router, vue-cli

I'm using vue cli to build a Spa. It is just a basic vue router code. After installing and using vue router, it is not displaying anything on my app.vue file.
I tried to inspect from console, but there is just a commented line, nothing else.
Here is the code
**main.js File**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import {route} from './router'
Vue.use(VueRouter);

const router = new VueRouter({
  route: route
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

**router.js file**

```
import Home from './component/home'
import User from './component/user'

export const route = [
    {path:'/', component: Home},
    {path:'/user', component:User}
]
```

**app.js file**

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <h1>This is main app</h1>
    <router-link to="/user">User</router-link>
    <router-link to="/">Home</router-link>
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
 
}
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

**user.vue file**

```
<template>
  <div>
      <h1>This is User page</h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {

}
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

**home.vue file**

```
<template>
  <div>
      <h1>This is home page</h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
}
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

Comment: `new VueRouter({ route: route })` should be `new VueRouter({ routes: route })` (with an **s**)

Comment: You are importing `App.vue`, but have `app.js` (according to your description)

Comment: Yes 's' was missing from `new VueRouter({ route: route })` file. Thank you for your help :)